# JEE Glassfish @schedule doesn't work

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, glassfish, schedule

I am first time using @Schedule in a stateless bean and for some reason it does not get executed by Glassfish though Glassfish says it was successfully deployed.
My Java version is 1.8.0_91
Glassfish version 4.1.1

I simplified the code more and more so right now my code is the one below at the bottom with the key line being: @Schedule(second="0", minute="*", hour="*")

I am using jdbc/__TimerPool as JDBC resource in Glassfish and can successfully execute a ping for  __TimerPool.

In my logs for Glassfish startup I found a stacktrace:
java.lang.NullPointerException which is very similar (first lines are the same as an open defect of Glassfish/Eclipse (https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21468) which according to what i read there is minor and thus should not prevent scheduing from working.

Anybody an idea whats wrong and how I can make this work?

Cheers
thorsten

here the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.ServerPlatformUtils.createServerPlatform(ServerPlatformUtils.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager.init(SessionManager.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager.<clinit>(SessionManager.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.addSessionToGlobalSessionManager(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:907)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.initSession(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2671)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:318)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:197)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:521)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.persistent.timer.TimerBean.findTimersByOwnerAndState(TimerBean.java:209)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.persistent.timer.TimerBean.findActiveTimersOwnedByThisServer(TimerBean.java:523)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy221.findActiveTimersOwnedByThisServer(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.persistent.timer.PersistentEJBTimerService.restoreEJBTimers(PersistentEJBTimerService.java:369)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.persistent.timer.PersistentEJBTimerService.resetEJBTimers(PersistentEJBTimerService.java:1400)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.initEJBTimerService(EJBTimerService.java:236)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.getEJBTimerService(EJBTimerService.java:205)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.getEJBTimerService(EJBTimerService.java:187)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.<init>(BaseContainer.java:825)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.<init>(StatelessSessionContainer.java:143)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.<init>(StatelessSessionContainer.java:137)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessContainerFactory.createContainer(StatelessContainerFactory.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:406)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:243)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:326)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
]]
```

here my bean:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;

@Stateless
public class PrintCenter implements PrintCenterRemote {
    public PrintCenter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Schedule(second="0", minute="*", hour="*")
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Test");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I need to start the domain in debug mode otherwise system.out.println is not put to server.log file :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PrintCenter as bean with @Startup@Singleton annotations.

Comment: Unfortunately did not work. Tried both<code>@Stateless @Startup </code> and <code>@Singleton @Startup</code>. Both without any effect.